# Django CSRF Error fixed by just visiting page in multi-page form?

Tags: python, django, cookies, web, csrf

I have two forms on two pages, one leads to the other. When "Submit" is pressed on page 1 it is supposed to take you to the form on page 2. Page 2 fails with "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." With the reason being "CSRF cookie not set."

The weird part is that if I go directly to Page 2, it loads fine. If I refresh the page and resubmit the form, I get 403'd again, but if, for example, I go into the address bar and just hit "Enter" to re-visit the page, it loads without the error. What gives?

I am using the most recent version of Django, I am using render in all my views and {% csrf_token %} in all my form tags.

Why would revisiting the page be fixing the 403 error? No login or authentication is happening between the forms. In fact, I don't even do anything with the data submitted in page 1 (yet).

Relevant code is as follows:

Page 1 Template:

```
<div class="">
    <div class="">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <p>What's up?</p>
        <form action="{% url 'core:getPageTwo' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input class="yellow_button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Page 2 View:

```
def getPageTwo(request):
    form = SomeForm()
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render (request, 'core/page_two.html', context)
```

Page 2 Template:

```
<div class="">
    <div class="">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. My HTTPS was messing up. So the fact that I had CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = TRUE was messing up all attempts to send a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your answer @thrillhouse :

`CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=True` makes the csrf token only work with ssl, like the docs also say:

> Whether to use a secure cookie for the CSRF cookie. If this is set to True, the cookie will be marked as “secure,” which means browsers may ensure that the cookie is only sent with an HTTPS connection.

So when you switch back to `HTTPS` connection, you should turn the value back to `True`.